# Export Outlook 2013 Search Folders emails to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I would like to **export my emails in the Search Folders to Excel**.

I am using the code below to export my email in the Inbox.

But with Search Folders it gives me an error :

> Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)
>
> The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.

```vb
Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()

Dim folders As Outlook.folders
Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim Pst_Folder_Name
Dim MailboxName

MailboxName = "xxx@yy.com"
Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"

Set folder = Outlook.Session.folders(MailboxName).folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

Sheets(1).Activate

For iRow = 1 To folder.Items.Count
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1).Select
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1) = folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2) = folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3) = folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 4) = folder.Items.Item(iRow).Categories
Next iRow

MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found

Comment: Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)'

Comment: What reference are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library, Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library, Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library, Visual Basic for Applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. It only works with one specified Search Folders, named in the variable: Pst_Folder_Name. If you have more search folders you have to use a cycle somehow.

```
Sub Outlook_Emails_Handled_Last_Week()
    Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores
    Dim oStore As Outlook.Store
    Dim oSearchFolders As Outlook.folders
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim Pst_Folder_Name
    Dim MailboxName
    Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    MailboxName = "xxxx@yyy.com"
    Pst_Folder_Name = "Emails Handled Last Week"

    Set oFolder = Session.Stores.Item(MailboxName).GetSearchFolders(Pst_Folder_Name)

    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Ws.Activate

    LastRow = Ws.Range("A" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Sender Name"
        Ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Subject"
        Ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Received Time"
        Ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Categories"

    For iRow = 1 To oFolder.Items.Count
        Ws.Cells(LastRow + iRow, 1) = oFolder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
        Ws.Cells(LastRow + iRow, 2) = oFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
        Ws.Cells(LastRow + iRow, 3) = oFolder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
        Ws.Cells(LastRow + iRow, 4) = oFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Categories

    Next iRow

    MsgBox "Completed!"

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As Search folders can be preassigned or custom, the best way to detect them is to check the folder's `.Class`, which should be `olSearch`.

So this should work (I added a new Integer to keep writing if there is more than one Search folder) :

```
Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()

Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim LastWrow As Integer
Dim MailboxName As String
Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet

MailboxName = "xxyy@zzz.com"
Set Ws = sheets(1)

For Each folder In Outlook.Session.folders(MailboxName).folders
    With folder
        If .Class <> olSearch Then
        Else
            Ws.Activate
            LastWrow = Ws.Range("A" & Ws.rows.Count).End(xlup).Row
            For iRow = 1 To .Items.Count
                'ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Select
                Ws.Cells(LastWrow + iRow, 1) = .Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
                Ws.Cells(LastWrow + iRow, 2) = .Items.Item(iRow).Subject
                Ws.Cells(LastWrow + iRow, 3) = .Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
                Ws.Cells(LastWrow + iRow, 4) = .Items.Item(iRow).Categories
            Next iRow
        End If
    End With
Next folder

MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. What if I have subfolders in the Search Folders?

Comment: Good question... If their types is not `olSearch`, I would say that the best way would be to loop this `For Each folder2 in folder.folders` with error handling if needed!

Comment: In my case I have 10 different subfolder based on who handled the email during the current year. (subfolder name = employee name)

Comment: Ok, so can you handle adding the loop on subfolders yourself?

Comment: I am not so professional like you. Can you please help me out?

Comment: I found an article which says: There's a different way of accessing search folders with VBA versus regular mail folders in Outlook. 
First, you will need to determine the display name of the Outlook store which contains your search folders.
Do you think Outlook.Stores is important in the code?

Comment: If it says so, most probably... Have you tried the code I posted? if it works, I'll add the loop for subfolders and if not, I'll look into Stores a bit later

Comment: It runs without any error, but gives back an empty excel sheet.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried to use break points to see if it goes inside `If .Class <> olSearch Then`? That's what's will be telling use if the `ClassType` actually work (I don't have any search folders on my Outlook and can't check for the moment)

Comment: It is not going inside the if. After `If .Class <> olSearch Then` it goes immediately to the `End If` line.

Comment: Ok so the `ClassType` was in facts useless... So, better look into `Stores`... I'll come back here if I found a solution! ;)